# Trying to cast dask array with shape=() array to float, but I'm getting "dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: arrays, dask, sparse-matrix

I'm working on some code for some research, and I'm taking the norm of the sum of a dask array and a scipy dia_matrix. This is giving me a dask array with shape=(), but when I try to get the value, it says `TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable`. I also tried this with numpy instead of dask, using a smaller matrix because numpy can't handle the matrices I'm working with on my computer.  Everything worked with numpy, so I'm thinking it's something with dask. Here's the part that's giving me an error:

```
import dask.array as da
from scipy.sparse import identity

I = identity(35344)
A = da.random.randint(0, high=5, size=(35344,35344))
obj_value = da.linalg.norm(A + I, ord="fro")
obj_value = float(obj_value)
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks for the help!

Update:
Here's the entire error message:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\samke\OneDrive - University of Kansas\Documents\KU\Research\Ashourvan Lab\Shared Papers\code\unfinished code\structure_function\test.ipynb Cell 4 in ()
      6 A = da.random.randint(0, high=5, size=(35344,35344))
      8 obj_value = da.linalg.norm(A + I, ord="fro")
----> 9 print(float(obj_value))

File c:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\threaded.py:89, in get(dsk, keys, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     86     elif isinstance(pool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
     87         pool = MultiprocessingPoolExecutor(pool)
---> 89 results = get_async(
     90     pool.submit,
     91     pool._max_workers,
     92     dsk,
     93     keys,
     94     cache=cache,
     95     get_id=_thread_get_id,
     96     pack_exception=pack_exception,
     97     **kwargs,
     98 )
    100 # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads
    101 with pools_lock:

File c:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:511, in get_async(submit, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, chunksize, **kwargs)
    509         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    510     else:
--> 511         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    512 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    513 state["cache"][key] = res

File c:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:319, in reraise(exc, tb)
    317 if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    318     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 319 raise exc

File c:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\local.py:224, in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    222 try:
    223     task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 224     result = _execute_task(task, data)
    225     id = get_id()
    226     result = dumps((result, id))

File c:\Users\samke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\dask\array\core.py:118, in getter(a, b, asarray, lock)
    116     lock.acquire()
    117 try:
--> 118     c = a[b]
    119     # Below we special-case `np.matrix` to force a conversion to
    120     # `np.ndarray` and preserve original Dask behavior for `getter`,
    121     # as for all purposes `np.matrix` is array-like and thus
    122     # `is_arraylike` evaluates to `True` in that case.
    123     if asarray and (not is_arraylike(c) or isinstance(c, np.matrix)):

TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Show the whole error message.  `identity(n)` produces a `dia` matrix, but I don't see an indexing step.  You may need to specify `identity(n, format='csr')` to get a subscriptable matrix.

Comment: Why two `obj_value =...` lines?  You haven't proofread the code

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated it.

Comment: What's `obj_value ` without the `float` attempt.

Comment: Here's what it looks like: dask.array<pow, shape=(), dtype=float64, chunksize=(), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>. There should just be one element in there.

Comment: One element from a `()` shape is accessed (in numpy) with `x.item()` or `x[()]`.

Answer (score 0):

With `from scipy import sparse`:

```
In [35]: M = sparse.identity(3)    
In [36]: M
Out[36]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements (1 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>
```

That type of sparse matrix cannot be indexed:

```
In [37]: M[0]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[37], line 1
----> 1 M[0]

TypeError: 'dia_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

nor does it make sense to apply `float` to it.

```
In [38]: float(M)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[38], line 1
----> 1 float(M)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'dia_matrix'
```

If we specify a 'format'

```
In [40]: M = sparse.identity(3,format='csr')

In [41]: M
Out[41]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [42]: M[0]
Out[42]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I donpt know or use `dask`, so can't test or say anything about how it wraps this `dia` matrix.